# Powershell: how to retrieve powershell commands from a csv and execute one by one, then output the result to the new csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a Commands.csv file like:

```
| Command                                        |
| -----------------------------------------------|
|(Get-FileHash C:\Users\UserA\Desktop\File1).Hash|
|(Get-FileHash C:\Users\UserA\Desktop\File2).Hash|
|(Get-FileHash C:\Users\UserA\Desktop\File3).Hash|
```

Header name is "Command"

My idea is to:

1. Use `ForEach ($line in Get-Content C:\Users\UserA\Desktop\Commands.csv ) {echo $line}`
2. Execute $line one by one via powershell.exe, then output a result to a new .csv file - "result.csv"

Can you give me some directions and suggestions to implement this idea? Thanks!

Comment: Use `Import-Csv path | % { & $_.Command }`

Comment: Hello Abraham, thanks for you advice. However, I got an error "BadExpression" around "{ & $_.Command }"

Comment: That will only work if your file has as its first line a header row with, in your case, a single header: `Command` or, if your file lacks a header row, use the `-Header` parameter to declare a single column header: `Import-Csv <path> -Header Command`. *It would be a good idea to edit your question and put your sample data in a code block rather than a table -- it's not obvious if "Commands" is the first row or not*.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, `&`, when given a string, only supports command _names_ / _paths_, not full commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Important**:

- Only use the technique below with **input files you either fully control or implicitly trust** to not contain malicious commands.
- To execute arbitrary PowerShell statements stored in strings, you can use **[`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression)**, but note that it **should *typically* be avoided**, as there are usually better alternatives - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).
- There are advanced techniques that let you *analyze* the statements before executing them and/or let you use a separate runspace with a restrictive language mode that limits what kinds of statements are allowed to execute, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.

---

- Given that your input file is a `.csv` file with a `Commands` column, import it with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) and access the `.Commands` property on the resulting objects.

  - Use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) only if your input file is a *plain-text* file without a header row, in which case the extension should really be `.txt`. (If it has a header row but there's only *one* column, you could get away with `Get-Content Commands.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1  | ...`). If that is the case, use `$_` instead of `$_.Commands` below.
- To also use the CSV format for the *output* file, all commands must produce objects of the same type or at least with the same set of properties. The sample commands in your question output *strings* (the value of the `.Hash` property), which cannot meaningfully be passed to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) *directly*, so a `[pscustomobject]` wrapper with a `Result` property is used, which will result in a CSV file with a single column named `Result`.

```bash
Import-Csv Commands.csv |
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{ 
      # !! SEE CAVEAT AT THE TOP.
      Result = Invoke-Expression $_.Commands 
    }
  } |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation Results.csv
```